# Only download from a link if it's an image in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I triend various methods but can't find the right one. In my current code with requests it downloads everything even if it's a text.

Comment: Will you be able to include what your current codes look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the response header you will get the type of file you are getting.
eg: for html: text/html , for image: image/png etc.. you can filter by putting the condition.

**Try this :**

```
import requests

response =requests.get("https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2Fb%2Fb6%2FImage_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png%2F1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FImage&tbnid=gxFxsvFBmxeZ9M&vet=12ahUKEwjAm6y6qYvrAhWVTnwKHRQVDAcQMygAegUIARDNAQ..i&docid=0JWe7yDOKrVFAM&w=1200&h=900&q=image&ved=2ahUKEwjAm6y6qYvrAhWVTnwKHRQVDAcQMygAegUIARDNAQ")

if response.headers["Content-Type"] =="text/html":
    pass
else:
    print(response.text)
```